# Generating random sequences that are harder to crack

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, random-seed

I am building a simple mobile game where players play rock paper scissors agains a computer. I am using Unity, and am looking to use the Random.Range function to determine which hand the computer plays against the player.

I see in Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) that they use an Xorshift 128 algorithm for the Random.Range function, which, according to [this blog post](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/08/22/cracking-random-number-generators-xoroshiro128/) and several other sources, can be easily cracked.

I'm wondering if there are ways to make it more "random" - I understand that true randomness cannot be achieved, but am wanting to learn ways to make harder to crack the pattern.

Any ideas will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: To a certain extend any "random" generator can be "cracked" ... but I'm pretty sure those people who actually do that will not use it to cheat in your rock-paper-scissors game ^^

Comment: Haha I agree, I was just curious to learn how I could make it more secure!

Answer (score 0):

You could use native c# random system which uses  [Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0).
Aswell as re-seeding based on rounds or time throughout the game. So you do not get a chance to fully crack each seed

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will look into both solutions.